# How to call javascript function after fancybox terminate to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i'm call fancybox in this way:

```
$(".add_exc").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 1000,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

where `.add_exc` is:

```
<a class="add_exc fancybox.ajax" href="ajax_content.php">
    <img src="click.png" />
</a>
```

in the ajax content i have some checkboxes and i need to check inside the parent window if some elements are present so that i can check the checkbox inside fancybox.

If i load javascript content inside the ajax content, it will be discarded.

How can i solve? thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried the Eval() function?

Comment: eval inside ajax content? no.. i try it now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with the fancybox callback `afterLoad`

```
$(".add_exc").fancybox({
    // all other API options
    closeEffect : 'none',
    afterLoad : function(){
     myFunction();
     // or some jQuery
     $variable = $(".selector:checked").val();
    }
});
```

Comment: is what i've done! ;) but i used beforeShow instead afterLoad otherwise $variable = $(".selector:checked").val(); could not get me value ;)